# Pass PHP object to another page via AJAX post

Tags: php, ajax

Anyone can help with this. I think i'm missing something basic and obvious!

I pass object $session from index.php to results.php like so..

index.php

```
include 'classes/user.php';
$session = new User();
//some object work
$sessionObjectStr = serialize($session);

<script>
var sessionObj = <?php if(isset($session)){echo json_encode($sessionObjectStr);}else{echo json_encode("");}; ?>;
$.post( 'results.php', {'object':sessionObj}, function(data){.....
</script>
```

results.php

```
include 'classes/user.php';
if(isset($_POST['object'])){ $session =  unserialize(($_POST['object']));}
$session->getName();
```

The getName method returns nothing. It should return name like it did on index.php page..

var_dump from index.php for serialized $session

```
string(690) "O:4:"User":7:{s:9:"*userId";s:2:"27";s:7:"*name";s:5:"Admin";s:8:"*email";s:13:"admin@nrt.com";s:9:"*rights";s:5:"Super";s:9:"*cookie";N;s:12:"*lastLogin";s:10:"1475435341";s:5:"*db";O:8:"Database":4:{s:7:"*link";O:6:"mysqli":19:{s:13:"affected_rows";N;s:11:"client_info";N;s:14:"client_version";N;s:13:"connect_errno";N;s:13:"connect_error";N;s:5:"errno";N;s:5:"error";N;s:10:"error_list";N;s:11:"field_count";N;s:9:"host_info";N;s:4:"info";N;s:9:"insert_id";N;s:11:"server_info";N;s:14:"server_version";N;s:4:"stat";N;s:8:"sqlstate";N;s:16:"protocol_version";N;s:9:"thread_id";N;s:13:"warning_count";N;}s:10:"*numRows";i:1;s:13:"*affectRows";i:1;s:9:"*result";b:1;}}"
```

var_dump from results.php for $_POST['object'] - (serialized)

```
string(690) "O:4:"User":7:{s:9:"*userId";s:2:"27";s:7:"*name";s:5:"Admin";s:8:"*email";s:13:"admin@nrt.com";s:9:"*rights";s:5:"Super";s:9:"*cookie";N;s:12:"*lastLogin";s:10:"1475435341";s:5:"*db";O:8:"Database":4:{s:7:"*link";O:6:"mysqli":19:{s:13:"affected_rows";N;s:11:"client_info";N;s:14:"client_version";N;s:13:"connect_errno";N;s:13:"connect_error";N;s:5:"errno";N;s:5:"error";N;s:10:"error_list";N;s:11:"field_count";N;s:9:"host_info";N;s:4:"info";N;s:9:"insert_id";N;s:11:"server_info";N;s:14:"server_version";N;s:4:"stat";N;s:8:"sqlstate";N;s:16:"protocol_version";N;s:9:"thread_id";N;s:13:"warning_count";N;}s:10:"*numRows";i:1;s:13:"*affectRows";i:1;s:9:"*result";b:1;}}"
```

So as you can see the serialized versions are the same.. Once i unserialize on the results.php i should be able to use the object as i did before right?

Edit:
As suggested, and what i tried before posting this question was the decode the variable and then unserialize it. But it returns an error

```
if(isset($_POST['object'])){ $decodeObjStr = json_decode($_POST['object']); $session =  unserialize($decodeObjStr);}
```

Fatal error: Call to a member function getName() on boolean

var dump for decoded_json.

```
 var_dump($decodeObjStr);
```

NULL

Comment: because encoding to json before making it serialized.

Comment: The whole idea of using a session is that the information is and stays on the server, there is no need to pass it to the user and the user cannot manipulate the information. Just use a real php session in both scripts: http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: Good point. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why? This is the first thing that popped into my head when reading your question. Why would you want to do this? It is a huge security risk, which can (and probably will) expose your users' details to a third party.
Not to mention, giving the users a trivial way to increase their own permissions by simply editing the HTML code in their browser's built-in tools..

Most importantly: Why not use the built-in functionality of sessions, and their associated cookie? That way you only need to run `session_start()`, and use the `$_SESSION` array to store stuff in. Also, no need to involve AJAX or even JavaScript on this, as this functionality is all server-side. Sending data to the client, for it to just re-send it back to the server unchanged, is a bit unnecessary. Especially when you can just store it on the server in the first place. Don't you agree? :)

In this case I **strongly** recommend using sessions. Store the userID in the session, and use this to re-create the user object on each load. Querying the database if necessary.
There should be absolutely no need to serialize the object, nor creating your own custom-built "session state engine".

Quick code example:
**index.php**

```
session_start ();

$user = new User ();
// Woodoo here, creating new user or logging in.

$_SESSION['userid'] = $user->getID ();

?>

<html>
<a href="results.php">Results</a>
</html>
```

**results.php**

```
session_start ();
$user = new User();

// Read the user's details from the DB, finalizing the object for use.
$user->read ($_SESSION['id']);

// Now we can do whatever we wanted to with the $user object.
```

Comment: I actually came across a fix for the issue i was having. But after reading your response. I understand that my approach was flawed. I have since amended my code to use session instead. 

However I am keep the whole object in a session var and not creating the object again on each page. This is due to having to query the DB on each new object creation. Is this OK approach? Just think it saves a DB call when we can store it instead

Comment: The call to the DB is (normally) not that expensive that it requires storing the object in session. In fact, if there is large enough amounts of data stored in the session querying the DB could actually be faster. Especially since the session is blocking (meaning only one instance of PHP can access it at a time), while DBs are not. Glad to hear that I could help improve your code and knowledge though. :)

Comment: Point in case: I had to change the session storage to a DB instead of flat files in a system we're using at work, because of a huge number of HTTP requests were simply sitting idle waiting for the previous ones to complete. After I changed it to use DBs, the load time went down from 10 minutes to a few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Use json_decode() built in PHP function before making it unserialized.

Comment: I tried this but it seems to cause an error

    Fatal error: Call to a member function getName() on boolean in

Comment: do you really need json encoding before before making serialized?